# Why am I not getting the NULL values when using FILTER to remove CSV Headers in PIG?

Tags: bigdata, apache-pig

I have this data below in a .csv file:

```
Needed_values,TEMP,Desc
,022.3,NewYork
3,022.30,India
,027.0,Australia
,027.00,Russia
1,027.1,Austria
,027.10,Norway
,036.2,Hungary
,036.20,Lithunia
2,785.52,Nigeria
```

I saw in one of the StackOverflow question the way to remove header using `FILTER`. So,
When I load this file in my pig script and use `Filter` to remove the header of my csv then all the `NULL` values under `Needed_values` also got removed!

```
LOAD_DATA = LOAD 'DATA.csv' Using PigStorage(',') as
(
NEEDED_VALUES:chararray,
TEMP:chararray,
DESC:chararray
);

FILTER_HEADER = FILTER LOAD_DATA BY NEEDED_VALUES != 'Needed_values';
```

```
ACTUAL OUTPUT:
(3,022.30,India)
(1,027.1,Austria)
(1,027.1,Austria)
```

I'm expecting the output to include everything except the headers- Needed_values,TEMP,Desc:

```
,022.3,NewYork
3,022.30,India
,027.0,Australia
,027.00,Russia
1,027.1,Austria
,027.10,Norway
,036.2,Hungary
,036.20,Lithunia
2,785.52,Nigeria
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null values will not pass the filter condition. Change the filter to:

```
FILTER_HEADER = FILTER LOAD_DATA BY NEEDED_VALUES != 'Needed_values' OR NEEDED_VALUES IS NULL;
```